# Angularjs form not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which inputs name of a country and then it overwrites a global variable. Submit button does nothing when clicked. Where am I missing?
Here is the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="InputController">
        <form class="form-wrapper cf" role="form">
            <input type="text" ng-model="model.country" placeholder="Search country..." required>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="update()">Search</button>
            <span>{{model.country}} ======</span>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And here is the controller.

```
LastFmApp.controller('InputController',
function InputController($scope) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.update = function() {
        console.log($scope.model.country);
    };
});
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/4j4bJurfxcMPOkXMHIiT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an issue with angular js.
The submit button will reload the page so you won't be able to see changes in your model.

You can either use an input type button with ngClick:

```
 <input type="button" ng-click="update()">Search</input >
```

Or an input type submit with ngSubmit attribute on your form:

```
 <form ng-submit="update()">
   <input type="submit">Search</input>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is any issue with your code [see](http://plnkr.co/edit/u9hqu1bASxxMgtEP1qAr?p=preview) your code is working in plunker

```
<div ng-controller="InputController">
        <form class="form-wrapper cf" role="form">
            <input type="text" ng-model="model.country" placeholder="Search country..." required>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="update()">Search</button>
            <span>{{model.country}} ======</span>
        </form>
    </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/u9hqu1bASxxMgtEP1qAr?p=preview